# Value of select Angular issue

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I have the following code:

component.html:

```html
<select id="select" (change)="updateValue(this.value)">
  <option *ngFor="let option of filteredOptions" value="{{option .Id}}"></option>
</select>
```

component.ts:

```
updateValue(value: number){
  this.value= value;
}
```

I can get the value of the select using jQuery or vanilla JS by selecting by ID.

**Question**

How can I pass in the value of the select using Angular?

Comment: can you make value="{{option.Id}}" to [value]="{{option.Id}}"

Answer (score 3):

For two-way binding, the `[(ngModel)]="value"` binding is missing. Try the following:

```
<select id="select" [(ngModel)]="selectedvalue">
      <option *ngFor="let option of filteredOptions" value="{{option .Id}}"></option>
</select>
```

Now you can use the "selectedvalue" in your component.

For one-way binding, use $event.value. Try the following:

```
<select id="select" (change)="updateValue($event.value)">
      <option *ngFor="let option of filteredOptions" value="{{option .Id}}"></option>
</select>
```

Demo: https://plnkr.co/edit/zxiDsiMg9GFA6nRxr5ly?p=preview

Comment: For two-way binding, I suggest to remove the `change` event handler.

Comment: Thanks @ConnorsFan, missed it

Answer (score 1):

I solved it

```
<select id="select" (change)="updateValue($event.target.value)">
      <option *ngFor="let option of filteredOptions" value="{{option .Id}}" class="select-option"></option>
</select>
```

Comment: I suggested the same in my answer. But i think there is no need to fire change event here. Two way binding is best option here.